# How can I change video frame with ffmpeg in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to merge two videos, but I need both to have the same frame height and width. Every video A has an different height and width, I would like to make an script to convert video B to the same frame heght and width of video A.

Im using fluent-ffmpeg library.
I tried:

```
require('fluent-ffmpeg')
var video_A_width = getWidth(pathA);
var video_A_height = getHeight(pathA);

var proc = ffmpeg('B.mp4').size(video_A_width+'x'+video_A_height)
                            proc.setFfmpegPath(mypath); 
   proc
                            .input('A.mp4')
                            .on('end', function() {
                                console.log('files have been merged succesfully');
                            })
                            .on('error', function(err) {
                                console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
                            })  
                            .mergeToFile("newvideo.mp4");

 Output: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Filtergraph scale=w=1280:h=720' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream ):), which is fed from a complex filtergraph
```

How can I do it?

Comment: which node ffmpeg library are you using

Comment: Im using: fluent-ffmpeg

Comment: You should figure out how to do this on the command line with ffmpeg before you start fighting with node.js bindings.